# How to update all Chocolatey packages except one?

Tags: chocolatey

`cup all -y` is used to update all [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) packages at boot. At the moment there is an issue in the latest version of VirtualBox, and I want to avoid that this package is updated at boot while the other packages need to be updated.

**Attempt to solve the issue**

I have checked the help function of the command:

```
C:\>cup all -h
Chocolatey v0.9.9.8
Upgrade Command

Upgrades a package or a list of packages. Some may prefer to use `cup`
 as a shortcut for `choco upgrade`.

Usage

    choco upgrade <pkg|all> [<pkg2> <pkgN>] [<options/switches>]
    cup <pkg|all> [<pkg2> <pkgN>] [<options/switches>]

NOTE: `all` is a special package keyword that will allow you to upgrade
 all currently installed packages.

Examples

    choco upgrade chocolatey
    choco upgrade notepadplusplus googlechrome atom 7zip
    choco upgrade notepadplusplus googlechrome atom 7zip -dvfy
    choco upgrade git --params="/GitAndUnixToolsOnPath /NoAutoCrlf" -y
    choco upgrade nodejs.install --version 0.10.35
    choco upgrade git -s "https://somewhere/out/there"
    choco upgrade git -s "https://somewhere/protected" -u user -p pass

Options and Switches

NOTE: Options and switches apply to all items passed, so if you are
 installing multiple packages, and you use `--version=1.0.0`, it is
 going to look for and try to install version 1.0.0 of every package
 passed. So please split out multiple package calls when wanting to
 pass specific options.


 -?, --help, -h
     Prints out the help menu.

 -d, --debug
     Debug - Run in Debug Mode.

 -v, --verbose
     Verbose - See verbose messaging.

     --acceptlicense, --accept-license
     AcceptLicense - Accept license dialogs automatically.

 -y, --yes, --confirm
     Confirm all prompts - Chooses affirmative answer instead of prompting.
       Implies --accept-license

 -f, --force
     Force - force the behavior

     --noop, --whatif, --what-if
     NoOp - Don't actually do anything.

 -r, --limitoutput, --limit-output
     LimitOutput - Limit the output to essential information

     --execution-timeout=VALUE
     CommandExecutionTimeoutSeconds - Override the default execution timeout
       in the configuration of 2700 seconds.

 -c, --cache, --cachelocation, --cache-location=VALUE
     CacheLocation - Location for download cache, defaults to %TEMP% or value
       in chocolatey.config file.

     --allowunofficial, --allow-unofficial, --allowunofficialbuild, --allow-unofficial-build
     AllowUnofficialBuild - When not using the official build you must set
       this flag for choco to continue.

 -s, --source=VALUE
     Source - The source to find the package(s) to install. Special sources
       include: ruby, webpi, cygwin, windowsfeatures, and python. Defaults to
       default feeds.

     --version=VALUE
     Version - A specific version to install. Defaults to unspecified.

     --pre, --prerelease
     Prerelease - Include Prereleases? Defaults to false.

     --x86, --forcex86
     ForceX86 - Force x86 (32bit) installation on 64 bit systems. Defaults to
       false.

     --ia, --installargs, --installarguments, --install-arguments=VALUE
     InstallArguments - Install Arguments to pass to the native installer in
       the package. Defaults to unspecified.

 -o, --override, --overrideargs, --overridearguments, --override-arguments
     OverrideArguments - Should install arguments be used exclusively without
       appending to current package passed arguments? Defaults to false.

     --notsilent, --not-silent
     NotSilent - Do not install this silently. Defaults to false.

     --params, --parameters, --pkgparameters, --packageparameters, --package-parameters=VALUE
     PackageParameters - Parameters to pass to the package. Defaults to
       unspecified.

 -m, --sxs, --sidebyside, --side-by-side, --allowmultiple, --allow-multiple, --allowmultipleversions, --allow-multiple-versions
     AllowMultipleVersions - Should multiple versions of a package be
       installed? Defaults to false.

 -i, --ignoredependencies, --ignore-dependencies
     IgnoreDependencies - Ignore dependencies when upgrading package(s).
       Defaults to false.

 -n, --skippowershell, --skip-powershell
     Skip Powershell - Do not run chocolateyInstall.ps1. Defaults to false.

     --failonunfound, --fail-on-unfound
     Fail On Unfound Packages - If a package is not found in feeds specified,
       fail instead of warn.

     --failonnotinstalled, --fail-on-not-installed
     Fail On Non-installed Packages - If a package is not already intalled,
       fail instead of installing.

 -u, --user=VALUE
     User - used with authenticated feeds. Defaults to empty.

 -p, --password=VALUE
     Password - the user's password to the source. Defaults to empty.
```

But it does not seem to have a function to exclude a certain package.

How to update all packages at boot, except one?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have two options: pin a package in advance, or exclude items during `choco upgrade`.

#### Pin Packages to Suppress Upgrades

You can pin any program you don't want updated.

Type `choco pin -h` for more details. If that command doesn't give you anything, please upgrade Chocolatey to at least 0.9.9.x.

> **Pin Command**
>
> Pin a package to suppress upgrades.
>
> This is especially helpful when running `choco upgrade` for all 
>   packages, as it will automatically skip those packages. Another 
>   alternative is `choco upgrade --except="pkg1,pk2"`.
>
> **Usage**
>
> ```
> choco pin [list]|add|remove [<options/switches>]
> ```
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> choco pin
> choco pin list
> choco pin add -n=git
> choco pin add -n=git --version 1.2.3
> C4B: choco pin add -n=git --version 1.2.3 --reason "'others may need to review'"
> choco pin remove --name git
> ```

**NOTE**: `--reason` option ONLY available in Chocolatey for Business (C4B).

#### Exclude Packages While Upgrading

Sometimes you just simply want to exclude items you would normally include in upgrades. You don't want pins as those are meant to live longer than a single command run. That is where the `Exclude` option comes in to your upgrade command.

As of Chocolatey v0.9.10, when calling upgrade, you can pass the optional [`--except`](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/293) as a switch for upgrade. An example would be `choco upgrade all --except="'conemu'"`.

Comment: Why `choco pin`? Is `cup all` deprecated?

Comment: Why would cup all be deprecated? Pin is a command that says "stay on this version for this package."

Comment: NOTE: To add a reason to a pin, you must have Chocolatey for Business (C4B).

Comment: What happens if I want to pin multiple packages? My use case: I want to upgrade most of my packages once a week but there are a few programs I use infrequently. I would like to upgrade the infrequent packages about once every two months. I plan to use pid add and pin remove for those occasions.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [official documentation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commandsupgrade):

```
choco upgrade all --except="'skype,conemu'"
```

Comment: On windows this will prevent the package to upgrade any more, even if you do not use except! The package folder is moved to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad`. If you want to upgrade again move it to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib`

Comment: The command doesn't work with single quotes in my case in Windows 10; so I just used quotes:  `cup all -y --except="mongodb"`.

Comment: @Metafaniel I don't know why they use both single and double quotes. But this is how it is officially documented. [https://chocolatey.org/docs/commandsupgrade](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commandsupgrade)

Comment: @Luke Sure but, only without single quotes worked for me. I just wanted to point it out. Thanks!